# Sql renaming several raw data

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have been through some solutions published here, but none of them solved my problem.

I want to set my username column to receive now unique usernames.

But for that I need to rename in certain situations, more than 1000 duplicated usernames already registered.

I tried this solution:

```
UPDATE profile n
JOIN (SELECT username, MIN(profile_id) min_id FROM profile
      GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) d
ON n.username = d.username AND n.profile_id <> d.min_id SET n.username = CONCAT(n.username, '1');
```

But it gives me for the same user name for example tony, tony1, tony11, tony111 and so on up to tony1111111111111... up to 1000, make the username have a long long lenght.

I would like a solution to get  only up 4digites after the username word. 0001,0002,0003,0004....1000

Can somebody help me here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like:

```
UPDATE profile n JOIN (
    SELECT profile_id, username, (@row_number:=@row_number+1) as cntr 
    FROM profile,  (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t 
    WHERE username IN ( SELECT username 
                FROM profile 
                GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
            and (username, profile_id) not in ( SELECT username, MIN(profile_id)
                FROM profile 
                GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
    ) d ON n.profile_id = d.profile_id 
SET n.username = CONCAT(n.username, d.cntr);
```

This is the best I can come up with at the moment.... the problem is that it will share the counter between all usernames... you you will have Alejandro, Alejandro1, Pedro, Pedro2, Juan, Juan3 .....

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but it gives an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':=@row_number+1 AS cntr 
       FROM profile GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) ' at line 4

Comment: I edited the query. maybe if you add the schema and some sample data I could use SQL fiddle and run the query.

Comment: I fixed the error but nw it gave me the following error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: how did you fixed it?, have you tried the new query?, but again, without the schema I cant test my sql :/

Comment: The error was here  SELECT username, MIN(profile_id) min_id, @row_number:= @row_number+1 AS cntr . Was missing the @ next to row_number. How can send you a piece of sample?

Comment: no, that whole  @row_number:= @row_number+1 AS cntr needs to be deleted (on the 2nd sub query.).... I already updated the post with the new sql, try it with the new one.

Comment: it gives the same error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: and added an alias to the 2nd sub query...  maybe now?

Comment: Why now it gives me this error? #1054 - Unknown column 'profile_id' in 'field list'? Profile_id is the ID's column name.

Comment: fixed. it was because the 1rst sub-query sees only the results from the 2nd one. and in the 2nd subquery we rename the field to min_id.

Comment: Weel it gives me the same result that I had before with my previous code. From the 1000 same usernames called Alejandro the first remained Alejandro and the 999 changed to Alejandro1. Updating again with the same code it remains de first Alejando1 and changes the other 998 to Alejandro11, then Alexandro111, Alexandro1111 and so on. To the time that we finish the 1000 updates it will have Alejandro plus 1000 figers next to the word. That is my proplem from the begining with my code.

Comment: The idea is to make the code to adding 1, or 2, or 3 and so on to each username, up to 1000, ending up the last username Alejandro1000.

Comment: are you sure that that is because this query in particular and not because the result of the previous update that you ran before?.

if you run 

    `select * from
    profile n JOIN (
       SELECT username, min_id, @row_number:=@row_number+1 as cntr FROM 
        (
           SELECT username, MIN(profile_id) min_id  
           FROM profile GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS t2 ,  (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t 
    ) d ON n.username = d.username `


it should give you a different number for each row.

Comment: I believe that you edited your code. A coped the code againg and I used it and gave me the same result

Comment: I copied again your code and used again and I aleady going on Alejandro, Alejandro1, Alejandro11, Alejandro111, Alejandro1111, Alejandro11111, Alejandro1111111

Comment: jummmm, I think I see the problem... maybe I can fix it with a `with` clause.... but it is difficult to do like this (me creating a sql, you running and telling me the result) if you could prepare a sqlFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schemas, I could help you more easily. :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this that you've commented is wrong...No Update. Only select:   select * from profile n JOIN ( SELECT username, min_id, @row_number:=@row_number+1 as cntr FROM ( SELECT username, MIN(profile_id) min_id FROM profile GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) AS t2 , (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t ) d ON n.username = d.username

Comment: nice!! i`m glad I was able to help!, could you then mark my post as the response? thnx

Comment: click on the check on the left side of the answer.. see this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png